# Unidentified hard disk space getting in OS X apps section

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility

Last night I got an issue with my MacBook Pro. After updating the OS to El Captain it shows the 50+ GB storage space for the Apps section. But after a couple of hours it shows 160 GB space. It's totally abnormal because OS capacity is not like 100+ GB, I didn't even install any other high capacity apps like Photoshop etc.. After I checked the forums thoroughly I installed an app called DaisyDisk to analyse the disk space. But the thing is it shows my filled hard disk space is 50 +GB . Now I'm struggling with these issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'm a newbie to the OS X operating systems. After long time scavenging through the forums I finally found a answer for that. Most of the people said it's a normal issue in the mac operating systems. It's because of the **Spotlight** indexing issue. If you guys have any trouble like this, use this method to solve your issues. I dropped here the link that I have found for my issue: [Rebuild the Spotlight index on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716). Hope this will help.